# Levi Decomposition of Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

When discussing Levi decomposition wikipedia mentions  **real** finite dimensional Lie algebras and later says such decomposition is not available in infinite dimension and in positive characteristic. From other sources I came to know such decomposition is available over $\mathbb{R} $ and $\mathbb{C}$.What I wonder that whether it is true over all $char=0$ fields ? Any help(may be with some reference) is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the theorem of Levi-Malcev holds for finite dimensional Lie algebras over any field of characteristic 0. See Bourbaki, Groupes et Algebres de Lie, ch. I, §6 no. 8. (Théorème 5 in particular.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Helped. Can I see any English online article/text ??

Comment: Most books on Lie algebras have it online, e.g., [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=0E8xRyVRSdYC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=theorem+of+Levi-Malcev&source=bl&ots=RQeOSfCmpC&sig=snLHxjGQx26j_QQlqVfy5Qkxz3Y&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil2quRvYnWAhWBvxQKHZheCusQ6AEISDAE#v=onepage&q=theorem%20of%20Levi-Malcev&f=false).

Comment: Thanks but characteristic is not easily found there also .

Comment: And also there are many possible semidirect products . It is not clear which particular semidirect product the theorem talks about . I hope it is when the action of semisimple part on the radical is given by adjoints .But then if we consider the Lie algebra to be one from the other semidirect products ,then what will be the Levi decomposition for that ?

Comment: @SKH your last question (in the comment) is very vague and I can't even guess what you're intending to ask.

Comment: What I know about  semidirect product(s) of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h} $  where  $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subalgebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal is that  it corresponds to one map $\phi :\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{der h}$. And Levi decomposition says any finite dimensional Lie algebra(char=0) is **the** semidirect product of ...  . What  I wanted to ask is that **the** semidirect product corresponds to which $\phi$? Is it assumed that **the** semidirect product is corresponding to $\phi(x)= ad x|_{\mathfrak{h}}$ ?

Comment: If so then how to write other semidirect products (corresponding to some other $\phi $'s) in that form corresponding to the above $\phi$ ? In particular, is $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes _\psi \mathfrak{h}  = \mathfrak{g} \ltimes \mathfrak{h}$ is the Levi decomposition  for any $\psi \in Hom_{Lie} (\mathfrak{g} , \mathfrak{ der h})$ ?

Comment: It should not be the case I guess !

Comment: Of course when you consider a Levi decomposition (or any semidirect decomposition) of a Lie algebra, ie decompose the Lie algebra as direct sum of an ideal and a subalgebra, you consider the adjoint action of the splitting subalgebra, not any exotic other action. There's no ambiguity about this in this context.